# perl multithreading perl exited with active threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, multidimensional-array

I write perl script to do a certain but I needed to mutlithread it, but I get this:

Perl exited with active threads:

2 running and unjoined

0 finished and unjoined

0 running and detached

Here is the code:

```
    use Net::Ping;
    use threads;
    use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);
    use threads::shared;

    my $starttime = Benchmark->new;
    my $finishtime;
    my $timespent;        
    my $num_of_threads = 2;
    my @threads = initThreads();        

    my $inFile = $ARGV[0] ;
    open(IN , "<$inFile") or die "can not find $inFile" ;
    my @output: shared = <IN>;
    chomp (@output) ;
    my $chunk_size = @output / 2;
    print($chunk_size);

    #############################
    ########  PROCEDURES ########
    #############################

    # Subroutine that intializes an array that will contain all our threads:
    sub initThreads{
        my @initThreads; # Our array
        for(my $i=1; $i<=$num_of_threads; $i++){
            push(@initThreads, $i);
        }
        return @initThreads;
    }

    sub doScript{

        my $id = threads->tid();
        print "//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Starting thread $id\n";
        my ($start, $end, $output) = @_;
        for my $i ($start .. $end) {

           ## some stuff done
            sleep 1 if 0.2 > rand;

        }

        print "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Thread $id done!\n";
        threads->exit();

    }
    ########################
    ########  MAIN  ########----------------------------------------------------------------
    ########################

    for my $chunk(1 .. 2){
        my $start = ($chunk - 1) * $chunk_size;
        push @threads, threads->create(
        \&doScript,
        $start,
        ($start + $chunk_size - 1),
        \@output,
        );
        print("finish");
    }
    # This tells the main program to keep running until all threads have finished.
    foreach(@threads){
        threads->join();
    }

    $finishtime = Benchmark->new;
    $timespent = timediff($finishtime,$starttime);
    print "\nDone!\nSpent ". timestr($timespent);

    #print "\nProgram Done!\nPress Enter to exit\n";
    $a = <>;


    close (IN);
```

I even replaced the join block with this:

```
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

the error was solved but the script seemed not to do anything, threads started and terminated without doing anything.

Can anyone help me with this !

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything except print a bunch of slashes. Do you see that output? Are you saying that you want help with the code that you've commented out `## some stuff done`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get that error is exactly as said on the tin - your code exited before the threads were closed. It can commonly happen when an exit or die is triggered early.

In particular I think your problem may lie within your reusing of `@threads` and `initThreads()`.

The latter returns a list of numbers, not any threads. And then you push a couple more threads to the end of the list later, when you're doing a `create`.

That looks a lot like some sort of logic error to me.

But the major problem I think will be this:

```
foreach(@threads){
    threads->join();
}
```

You're not actually joining a specific thread.  What you *probably* want is:

```
foreach my $thr ( @threads ) {
  $thr -> join();
}
```

At least, you would, if you hadn't manually populated `@threads` with `[1,2]` thanks to `my @threads = initThreads();`